# How to make a certain column number the first one shown

Tags: column

If I want a certain row to be the first that is shown, I press `C-l C-l`. Now I'm looking for the same thing with columns. 
I imagine it like this:
I move the cursor to the desired column, do "blank", and said column becomes the first column visible. Changing rows does not change that first column.

Answer (score 3):

Keeping in mind that column numbers are zero-based, and assuming that column zero is currently visible, then you can use `scroll-left` with the desired column as a prefix argument. e.g.:

<kbd>C-u</kbd> `16` <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd><</kbd>